# How do i determine maximum or minimum at (1,1) of function $ f(x,y)=(x-y)^{4} + (y-1)^{4}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do i determine maximum or minimum at this point of function

$$ f(x,y)=(x-y)^{4} + (y-1)^{4}$$

I am getting doubtful case at point (1,1). How do i furthure investigate whether it is point of minima or maxima

Thanks

Comment: in general, take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization#Classification_of_critical_points_and_extrema

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**:

Notice that you add $2$ **non - negative** terms! Thus, $f(x,y) \ge 0,$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$. For which $x,y$ does it hold $f(x,y) = 0$?